# Keyframes cssAnimation percentage?

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to use the following code to objects float from left to right in the background. Unfortunately when it goes off screen a vertical scroll bar appears despite the `overflow-y: hidden` attribute added to the class. I tried percentage (100% with the to transition) but it didn't work. I don't know it's supposed to? I was hoping someone could tell me how to fix this, if it is fixable using just CSS.

```
.largest-slowest {
  border: solid 0px #2d2d2d;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: -1000;
  background: #575757;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  overflow-y:hidden;
}

.largest-slowest {
    -webkit-animation: cssAnimation 12.7734s  16 linear;
    -moz-animation: cssAnimation 12.7734s  16 linear;
    -o-animation: cssAnimation 12.7734s  16 linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes cssAnimation {
    from {-webkit-transform:  rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(0deg) translate(-100px);}
    to { -webkit-transform:  rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(0deg) translate(2000px); } 
}
@-moz-keyframes cssAnimation {
    from { -moz-transform:  rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(0deg) translate(-600px); }  
    to { -moz-transform:  rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(0deg) translate(2000px); } 
} 
@-o-keyframes cssAnimation {
    from { -o-transform:  rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(0deg) translate(-600px); } 
    to { -o-transform:  rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(0deg) translate(2000px); } 
}
```

Comment: FYI: You vendor prefixes are all messed up. You need the standard unprefixed `animation` and `@keyframes` at least, and duplicate the rules for each property, and make sure you have the unprefixed `transform` too.

Comment: I'm so sorry, @-moz-keyframes cssAnimation and @-o-keyframes cssAnimation are both there, but I forgot to copy/paste them into my above post. Correcting now.

Comment: You also need the standard non-prefixed version, `animation:` and `@keyframes`. The vendor prefixed versions are deprecated and even obsolete in some browsers.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the comment above, you need to add `overflow-y: hidden` to the parent of `.largest-slowest` instead of to `.largest-slowest` itself. So if you don't want the window to scroll when `.largest-slowest` goes off the screen, your CSS should look something like:

```
body {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.largest-slowest {
    border: solid 0px #2d2d2d;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: -1000;
    background: #575757;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: I added overflow-y:hidden to the body tag, and I corrected my question to include @-moz-keyframes cssAnimation and @-o-keyframes cssAnimation, which I had left out in error. No luck, it still makes a scroll bar, but other than that it works just the way I want it to.

Comment: @Isadorabelle Is it the vertical or horizontal scrollbar that is showing up? If it's horizontal, try setting `overflow-x: hidden`

Comment: It's the vertical. I tried overflow-y: hidden but no luck.